# "In the meantime" vs. "for the meantime"

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

"In the meantime" and "for the meantime" are both listed in dictionaries. I'd lke to know which should be used in the following. If either is okay, is there a scenario where one but not the other can be used?

> The power supply should be back soon. **In**/**For** the meantime we’ll have to use candles.

Answer (score 1):

"In the meantime" and "for the meantime" mean the same thing. The main difference is that using "in" is very common, and using "for" is rare.

Answer (score -1):

Interesting. Upvoted.

[**There was a same question at WorldReferenceCom**](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/for-the-meantime-or-in-the-meantime.128836/) and an answer seemed to have convinced the OP saying,

> They are quite similar. I found it hard to make a distinction! they both mean "from now until something else that I expect to happen happens" If I say I'm doing something "for the meantime" , it means for example: I want to buy a car, I don't have enough money but in 3 months I will, so for the meantime I'm taking the bus. It would not, however be incorrect to say in the meantime.

> Generally "in the meantime" is used when you are waiting for something to happen, so you do something else until the other thing or person is ready. You go to the deli and order some meat to be sliced - the slicer is being used, so the fellow serving you says, we have to wait a minute for the slicer, what can I get you in the meantime? Over all, I feel they are pretty well interchangeable. I'll be interested to hear what others have to say!

P.S Others say such as,

> Therefore, there's no strong reason why one couldn't say "for the meantime", even though I've never encountered it myself. "For the meantime" just isn't idiomatic in the places I've lived, but apparently it is elsewhere, to judge by the other comments.You've got me interested.

Comment: Why did I get downvote? I just copied and pasted the same question and answers in another site. Don't you like the Aisans responds in any form? Huh?

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer, but I can see why it got a downvote: it lacks a summary and synthesis of the various  comments you quoted. In other words, it strikes readers as messy and disorganized.